# ORA-01882 after creating function based index with TIMESTAMP expression from dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: database, oracle, timezone, indices

We have a big existing script that drops and recreates tables in (a clone of) our customers database. Our customer might have changed table or index definitions slightly, so our script tries to use the output from `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to recreate the tables, but we have problems with function based indices with timestamp expressions. Minimalistic example emulating a customer table:

```
create table t(a timestamp, b timestamp);
create index idx_ta on t (nvl(a, TO_DATE('2010-01-02 03:04:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
create index idx_tb on t (nvl(b, TO_DATE('2010-01-02 03:04:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
```

Our script attempts to look at the existing database by processing the output from `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`. For example:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX','IDX_TA') from dual;
```

Output (cropped): `CREATE INDEX "MYUSER"."IDX_TA" ON "MYUSER"."T" (NVL("A",TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-02 03:04:05'))`

Our scripts reads this output and attempts to use it to recreate the table and indices like this (I will call the clone created by our script U here to distinguish the recreated version from the original):

```
create table u(a timestamp, b timestamp);
create index idx_ua on u (nvl(a, TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-02 03:04:05'));
create index idx_ub on u (nvl(b, TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-02 03:04:05'));
```

`idx_ua` is created without error messages, but `create index idx_ub` fails with:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01882: tidszoneregionen  blev ikke fundet
01882. 00000 -  "timezone region not found"
```

In general, everything fails after creating `idx_ua`, for example `insert into u values (null,null);` fails with the same error message.

`idx_ua` looks like this (cropped output from get_ddl): `CREATE INDEX "MYUSER"."IDX_UA" ON "MYUSER"."U" (NVL("A",TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-02 03:04:05,000000000'))`

We tried doing `alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format=...` to make sure the output from `get_ddl` will use a predetermined timestamp format, but it has no effect. In fact, `get_ddl` outputs different timestamp formats for different indices, even though as far as we know, all our indices were created in the same way. We suspect it depends on the client that was used to create the index. This also means the output from `get_ddl` is essentially useless when it comes to timestamps.

We tried on both Oracle 11 and 12. The examples here use only SQL Developer.

What we need is a (more) reliable way to drop and recreate tables like the above in an automated way. Using an alternative to get_ddl, tweaking some parameters that affect get_ddl, running some additional query for indices containing timestamps - whatever gets the job done.

Comment: I'm a SQL Server person, not Oracle, but couldn't you just truncate the tables instead of dropping and recreating?  Then you retain all of the table and index definitions.

Comment: Good point Jen R. Our task more complex than described - we need to delete MOST, but not of the data in order to reclaim space but still leave some essentials. So truncate alone doesn't solve the problem - we would have to rewrite the script to use a copy + truncate + (re)insert design.

Comment: Index function `NVL(a, TIMESTAMP '2010-01-02 03:04:05')` does not make any sense to me: What do you try to achieve with this index?

Comment: The database processes many queries that specifically contain an expression like `NVL(a, TO_DATE('2999-12-31 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, and as far as I understand it, adding indices that contained these frequently used expressions were added because without them, the query plan was horrible. As for why the queries themselves look like they do, the general idea is just to treat a `null` timestamp like "the distant future", but beyond that I cannot answer - the database was designed years ago.

Comment: Seems to be a case for Oracle Support. On my database it works all without any error.

Comment: Since this occurs for us both on Oracle 11 and 12, and it does not occur in your database Wernfried, we suspect either something in our configuration or something in our data is triggering this - million dollar question is what, specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, execute the following before applying your indexes.

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

The error is caused by Oracle bug 16731148 and occurs after you create function based indices involving timestamps while your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting is not ',.'. The bug causes Oracle to erroneously generate a comma in the timestamp representation (TIMESTAMP' 2010-01-02 03:04:05,000000000') due to NLS settings even though the timestamp should have an NLS-independent syntax. The error exists in 11.2, and is fixed in 12.2.0.3.

If your database is already corrupted, you must drop the relevant indices, and then recreate them after setting NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS as indicated above. You can quickly determine if a table T has a corrupted index if a simple `select 1 from T` results in the ORA-01882 error.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `TO_DATE(...)` on a `TIMESTAMP` column, this requires an implicit cast.

Better use `TO_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-02 03:04:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` or  `TIMESTAMP '2010-01-02 03:04:05'` which is the same, just written as literal.

Are you sure the datatype is really `TIMESTAMP` not `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE`?

Comment: `describe` shows the datatype as `TIMESTAMP(3)` - I assume this means without timezone.

Comment: As for using `to_timestamp` when creating the indices - that sounds like the/a right thing to do, but the customer database is already in operation, so it's not among our options.