# ORA-01882 when trying to perform any action on table

Tags: oracle

I've created a virtual column an index over it in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 in such a way:

```
ALTER TABLE EX_TABLE ADD GREATEST_T GENERATED ALWAYS
    AS (
      GREATEST(
        NVL(START_T, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'),
        NVL(END_T, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'),
        NVL(SUSPEND_T, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001'),
        NVL(RESUME_T, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001')
      )
    );
CREATE INDEX IDX_EX_TABLE_GREATEST_T ON EX_TABLE (GREATEST_T);
```

After that I've got `ORA-01882: timezone region not found` when trying to select smtg from `EX_TABLE` table (other tables are fine). I thought that I've faced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772491/ora-01882-after-creating-function-based-index-with-timestamp-expression-from-dbm) issue once again, so I deleted the index `IDX_EX_TABLE_GREATEST_T`. But the error still persists, and I cannot even delete the `GREATEST_T` column which is causing the problem I think.
This doesn't look machine-specific (tried different clients/PCs).

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Why can't you drop that column? And what is the definition of the rest of the table, e.g. as reported by `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`?

Comment: @AlexPoole when I try to execute `alter table EX_TABLE drop COLUMN GREATEST_DATE` I get `ORA-01882 ...`

The table definition is as following: [link](https://pastebin.com/GEj32BYF)

Comment: Well, that shows the issue, you have commas in the DDL instead of periods.

Comment: @AlexPoole is it because of wrong NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting during the original script execution? Any idea of how to fix this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't actually see how you created the table with that definition; NLS chars don't apply in a literal. You should have got ORA-01882 on `create` or `alter`. Interesting. I can't recreate in 11.2.0.4 Was it created from that script, or maybe imported (imp, or impdp?) or created by some other less common method, maybe over OCI?

Comment: @AlexPoole if you mean the `GREATEST_T` column it was added to the existing table by the script listed in the original post. In fact it was a part of Liquibase changeset. 
The curious thing is that I used to add this column/index for testing purposes running this script by hand in SQL Developer before (from another PC), and it was all OK.

Comment: Oh, OK, the bug in the linked question was fixed in 11.2.0.4.2 according to MOS note 1611785.1. So that's why I can't recreate it. You might be able to apply a PSU, but not sure if that will fix an existing issue, you may still have to recreate the table (which is a pain particularly if there are FK references, of course).

Comment: @AlexPoole I've checked the logs, there was an error message during the script execution 
`[ERROR] Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01882: timezone region not found
[ERROR] [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX IDX_EX_TABLE_GREATEST_T ON EX_TABLE (GREATEST_T)]`

Comment: Yes, but the table was already broken by then, sadly. (There seems to be inconsistency between `GREATEST_DATE` and `GREATEST_T` too, but not sure that's relevant; you may have edited names.)

Comment: Yup, I've edited names, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @AlexPoole btw nothing helped to restore the table data, even patching Oracle.

Comment: Sorry to hear that; did you raise an SR with Oracle to see if they could help? I also assume you tried things like export (data pump and legacy) to see if they could salvage anything? I would think they'd get the same errors but you never know as they work in obscure ways.

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't think we have a corresponding support contract which would let us call Oracle. Regarding data pump: yes, we've tried it among other options but any operation attempt on our table just raises ORA-01882. But if we create an empty table with the same definition, inserts/selects work (after patching Oracle).